# Is it possible to create a parachute large enough to stop all velocity?

Tags: gravity, air, free-fall

This idea came to me while playing Kerbal Space Program. I noticed that the larger my parachute was, the slower my rocket would fall back down to Kerbin. I would like to know if it is possible to create a parachute so large in the real world that it might stop all velocity, essentially making whatever is attached to it float in mid-air. Common sense is telling me "no," but I could always be wrong, and I would love some explanation behind whether or not it is possible.

Comment: No, because air resistance only acts when you're moving. But the terminal velocity could in principle be made arbitrarily small, I think.

Comment: I think it is called a kite. Wait, I haven't seen one large enough for a person.

Comment: Hot air balloon comes to mind, though it's not quite the same as a kite.

Comment: What would stop the parachute from falling??

Comment: Of course @JavierBadia's comment applies to a simple, static atmosphere. If you have any action you can take advantage of thermals. Of course, you'll want to have active steering at which point you have a soft-wing glider. I think we have a site for that: [aviation.se].

Comment: Theoretically, maybe; if you created a parachute with enough mass compared to the rest of the universe, then other objects would be drawn to its gravitational pull, rather than vice versa. I say maybe, because the gravity of smaller objects still pulls larger objects, even if its overwhelmingly canceled out by the gravity of the larger object.

Comment: Keep in mind that KSP has a halfway decent orbital model, a somewhat flawed model of the mechanical forces between your rocket parts, and a very flawed aerodynamical model. Unfortunately, parachute physics are primarily aerodynamic.

Comment: Yes, a spherical parachute which encompasses the whole planet. Air cannot escape from the edges.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No. All parachutes, whether they are drag-only (round) or airfoil (rectangular) will sink. Some airflow is needed to stay inflated, and that airflow comes from the steady descent.

Whether your *net descent rate* is positive or negative is a different question. It is quite easy to be under a parachute and end up rising (I have done it myself), you just need an updraft in excess of your descent rate. Never lasts though, as a permanently floating parachute would violate a couple of laws of nature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had not thought about the parachute deflating, that's a great point. Thanks to all the people who commented on my question, too. Awesome answers all around! :)

Comment: However, if you are very small and light, like dandelion seeds or balooning spiders, you can sometimes "parachute" for weeks!

Comment: @szulat: if you're small enough (microscopic), gravity becomes essentially irrelevant.

Comment: which laws of nature are violated

Comment: @coburne: What goes up must come down :)

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. However, while a particular updraft may not last forever, it's quite possible to find enough updrafts to stay aloft more or less indefinitely. It's also not inconceivable for a particular geographic feature or atmospheric phenomenon to produce a more-or-less persistent updraft. The heating from an active volcano, for instance. Also, the core updraft at the center of a large low pressure center can last for quite a long time. Hadley cells (due to global solar heating patterns) also lead to more-or-less persistent updrafts near the equator.

Comment: I think you really mean the law of probability, because it is explicit about time.

Comment: `a permanently floating parachute would violate a couple of laws of nature.` No. Might offend sensibilities about what constitutes a parachute, though. If you could create a large enough parachute out of light enough materials (lighter than the atmosphere they're operating in), such that your parachute and payload had a combined specific gravity equal to or less than that of the atmosphere, then you would end up with such a "parachute".  ... it just would be debatable as to whether or not this could be properly called a "parachute," because of the mechanism of operation it uses.

Comment: @reirab I'm not a physicist nor have I ever skydived before, but I have a feeling parachuting over an active volcano seems like a terrible idea...

Comment: @corsiKa Agreed. I was just pointing out that it doesn't actually violate any laws of physics, not suggesting that it's a good idea. :) Parachuting in the ITCZ probably isn't a great idea, either, but, in theory, it should work.

Comment: @HopelessN00b if your parachute and payload had a combined specific gravity equal to or less than that of the atmosphere we would call it a balloon, not a parachute.

Answer (score 25):

It would be possible in theory, but only in a very side-thinking way: if you make a parachute so large it encapsulates the whole Earth, it will in effect act as a balloon and not fall down, due to the internal pressure of the atmosphere.

This wouldn't work in practice for obvious reasons, but maybe in Kerbal you might be able to do something like it..

Comment: I shouldn't be upvoting this, but I was thinking the same thing as I read the question.

Comment: Even in KSP you couldn't make a parachute around the entire atmosphere.  One lesson you learn from KSP is just how big the world is compared to your tiny craft.

Answer (score 13):

A parachute is a device specifically designed to create viscous friction.
Viscous friction generates a force that:

1. is oriented opposite to the velocity;
2. is proportional to (a certain power of [*]) the velocity.

So the falling velocity will increase until the drag force (pointing upwards) becomes equal to the weight of the falling object (pointing downwards). This equilibrium velocity can be reduced increasing the drag, but cannot be killed completely (unless you have infinite drag) because this would kill the drag force.

If you want to stop the motion you need another force, this can be the [buoyant force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_principle) (but then you have an aerostat). Another possibility is to have an upward air flow, then you will be falling with respect to air being steady with respect to ground.

<sub>[*] Typically $F\propto v$ for small [Reynolds number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) and $F \propto v^2$ for big Reynolds number</sub>

Comment: Surprised this answer does not have more up-votes - it is the most direct answer here and the only one specifically noting the key fact that the drag requires some (air) velocity.

Answer (score 6):

It could be possible if the parachute was very large, rigid, shaped like a floating object, and you started descending from the vacuum of space. In this case the parachute would float on top of the atmosphere. It's easier to visualize if you imagine the parachute being a boat and you fell into some water; the boat would float on top of the water and reduce your velocity to zero.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea, might be a good invention!

Comment: Actually, this has already been invented, except that it doesn't need to start from space and actually works much better at lower altitudes than at the edge of space. It's called... a balloon. :) Also, blimps and dirigibles. This principle actually works better at lower altitudes because the on which you're floating is more dense. Water, on the other hand, is not appreciably compressible, so that's why you don't float much better at lower depths in the water than you do on the surface. Also, water has surface tension that helps with floating.

Comment: @reirab is that the same? A balloon is closed and contains, eg, hot air or helium to make its overall mass less than that of the air it displaces (aka "bouyant"). I think Thomas is suggesting something with no top, which "contains" empty space in the way that a rowboat on a lake contains air. I guess the trick is to build it out of something light and strong enough, a material which is to air as wood is to water, so the shell + its internal vacuum doesn't weigh more than the air it displaces.

Comment: @user3764 I meant more the concept of 'floating on the atmosphere' than his actual particular suggested design. Certainly, buoyancy has been used by aviation for quite a long time. In order for the 'open top' design to work, the top of the hull would have to remain outside the atmosphere, just as the top the hull of a boat has to remain above the water level. Finding a material strong enough to not collapse and light enough that it actually could float on the extremely sparse atmosphere at high altitudes would be very difficult. A balloon is much easier and accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: The atmosphere gains in pressure too gradually for you to float anything that is reasonably sized on it

Answer (score 4):

The closest you are going to get is a parachute large enough to slow your descent to the point where you can find lift in rising air and climb away.

They exist and are called paragliders! Strictly speaking they are still falling at 1 to 2 metres per second but rely on rising air ( thermals, ridge etc ) to 'fall' slower than a parcel of surrounding air.

Some large cumulonimbus clouds are big enough to even 'suck' up a normal parachute and I have flown under big storms that appear to be sucking so hard that a bag of cement would stay airborne!

But in still air you are stuck with air flow causing drag so movement of some sort is required.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ["cloud suck"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cloud_suck).

Answer (score 4):

Without the ability to change the shape of the parachute, no.  With the ability, yes - briefly.

A modern square parachute acts as a wing, producing enough lift to slow the descent of the vehicle, but it relies on forward momentum to do so and to remain inflated.  If the trailing edge of the parachute is pulled down quickly, the air moving under the wing will be deflected down, generating a lot of lift for a brief moment.  This is called "flaring".  With the right training, under the right conditions, a parachutist can stop themselves dead in the air relative the ground.  Doing this right before you hit the ground is the trick to landing on your feet.

Comment: Flaring sounds suspiciously like flapping...

Answer (score 3):

I will answer "yes" if you think out of the box for a parachute, which is a way for a person ejected from a plane to fall on the earth safely.

Theoretically, one might design a parachute with a layer  of helium so as to match the parachute and person downward gravitational force at a certain height, possibly 4 km above ground so as to avoid mountains, with an upward buoyant one. The helium could be compressed and released in the parachute when pulling a cord while ejected or falling.

Of course it would be of no use as a parachute , unless one slowly emptied the helium controlling the rate of fall.  (It should  also have the parachute usual shape and strength as a backup in case the system did not work for some defect).

Helium is very expensive. One could ignore the explosive danger and use hydrogen , after all it could be compressed in a strong enough module not to present problems during normal flights. Such a parachute will ensure a safe landing as the person could choose the spot to land by slowly deflating the parachute/balloon and drifting to better spots.

Comment: It would be an [aerostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerostat) in fact in this case, not a parachute.

Comment: @Ruslan that is why I defined Parachute, it is a method to preserve the life of the ejected pilots/passangers. It is not suppose to stay in the air , but help in the safety, which is why parachutes were invented. An aerostat serves a differnt function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The trick is to have a parachute which is large enough that it's Schwarzschild radius extends down to the object it is lifting.

Under such a circumstance, the parachute would stop ALL motion of the object it is lifting.

PS I just watched Interstellar :D

Comment: I was about to upvote as this is a nice idea. Then I saw that you seem to just cite Interstellar and decided to think about it for a bit longer. Finally, have an upvote, but a smaller one than initially planned.

Comment: @phresnel Would you prefer I cite Schwarzschild's Metric? To show that a 4 vector at the Schwarzschild Radius would be completely rotated?

Comment: I am not into this topic, but this would be cooler than citing popular science fictions :D